# 'es mit etwas versuchen'

Tags: phrase, idiom

'Es mit etwas versuchen'

This is given as an exemplar idiomatic verbal phrase in my grammar book as 'to try ones hand at something'. However, I can find no example of it on the internet. Can somebody please verify if this is an idiom that is in usage?

Maybe:

> Ich versuche es mit Fußball?

Comment: The first thing which comes to my mind is this: https://youtu.be/v_EWWyJfgPc (_probieren_ is a synonym of _versuchen_).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I hadn’t noticed. Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke ;}

Answer (score 2):

> "Ich wollte kochen, aber das Essen wird nicht heiß." --
> "Hast du den Herd eingeschaltet?" --
> "Gute Idee, ich werde es mal damit versuchen."
>
> "Der Arzt sagt, ich soll Sport treiben, aber mein Fuß schmerzt. Ich werde es nun mit Schwimmen versuchen."

Yes, this idiom is in use in Germany*, but I daresay it's only used in direct speech. Since a whole lot of content on the net is not direct speech, and this idiom is seldom found in it's pure form (i.e. without any additional words in between), I imagine you'd have trouble finding some examples.

*) at least in North-Rhine Westphalia, where I live. But I never saw anyone not understanding that phrase.

Comment: Only in direct speech? I don't think so, and I live in NRW too. You can see sentences like "Wenn es mit Seife nicht rausgeht, können Sie es mit Spiritus versuchen" in writing too.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis To my knowledge: that example is direct speech, quoted in writing (I may be hazy on the definition of "direct speech", so if you've got a definition source, I'm all ears). --- Totally unrelated: I've seen your name before. Have you been active in dclpd and the usenet in general in the late 90s?

Comment: @orithena: no, you can see it on "Ratgeber" sites too, and there it is not quoted direct speech. I think that saying it is only used in direct speech is wrong. OT: No idea what DCLPD is, but I have been on Usenet since the late nineties, yes.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'd still argue that this is kind of direct speech, because the Ratgebers you're referring to are worded like talking to the reader. But yeah, I see your point. This is going to the definition territory. OT: dclpd = de.comp.lang.pascal.delphi; so ... Hello from 20 years ago. Your name is one of the first I came across when diving into usenet back then. And somehow, it stuck to my mind. (I signed my posts back then with "Dave KLiczbor", because I was typing the KL so fast that I didn't have time to release the shift key)

Comment: @orithena: I wouldn't argue like that. That is not direct speech.

Comment: And yes, i was quite busy an d.c.l.p.d. those days.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more common when used like this:
"Wir hatten uns zwar getrennt, aber ich werde es noch einmal mit ihm/ihr versuchen."
(We broke up, but I will give it one more try / I will give him or her one more chance)

Edit:
Examples on the internet can be found here: https://www.google.de/search?ei=zlNaW5H8N-GE6ATgvKPwDw&q="es+noch+einmal+mit+ihr+versuchen"#

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time to find a printed example but succeded via DWDS in *Korpora search* in [Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/2014_20_griechenland-zagori-viskos-schlucht):

> Die Zeit, 08.05.2014, Nr. 20:
> Einige Hotelbesitzer wollen es jetzt damit versuchen, Touristen in Igoumenitsa, dem nächstgelegenen Fährhafen, Broschüren in die Hand zu drücken, [...]

(Some hotel owners will now give it a try to distribute leaflets to tourists at the next ferry port.)

or

> Die Zeit, 08.06.2011, Nr. 23: Der Hersteller will damit versuchen, mehr Männer hinter das Steuer eines Minis zu bekommen.